# Is there a way to specify a custom dependency property's default binding mode and update trigger?

Tags: c#, data-binding, dependency-properties

I would like to make it so that, as default, when I bind to one of my dependency properties the binding mode is two-way and update-trigger is property changed. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example of one of my dependency properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectionLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BindableSelectionLength",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(ModdedTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnBindableSelectionLengthChanged));
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

When registering the property, initialize your metadata with:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
{
    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
    DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
}
```

Comment: I was able to set BindsTwoWayByDefault by adding this to my example dp:
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnBindableSelectionStartChanged). However, I am still having trouble setting the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to do it with an object initializer. Use that instead of a constructor.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon is there a way to allow only OneWay Binding mode ?

Comment: Very Cool,I'm just hunting for implementing TwoWay mode by hand.

Comment: @Justin `DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger= UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` does the trick

Comment: Guess it's worth noting that it's not possible to change the default to any other mode than `TwoWay`. So `OneTime` and `OneWayToSource` are excluded. At least I didn't find a way.

Answer (score 24):

In the Dependency Property declaration it would look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(Dock), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            OnIsExpandedChanged));

public bool IsExpanded
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
}
```