# TemplateBinding not working for textbox text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties, templatebinding

I have a custom control called `EnhancedTextBox` which is a UserControl that has a `TextBox` and a `Button`. To the consumer I want it to mostly look like a TextBox, so I did the following:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="textBoxes:EnhancedTextBox">
    ...
    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"...
```

And in EnhancedTextBox I have

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (String), typeof (EnhancedTextBox));

public String Text
{
  get { return (String) GetValue(TextProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

Yet, when I use it as the following:

```
<EnhancedTextBox Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}" />
```

Then, `MyText` is never updated, as well as I inspect `EnhancedTextBox.Text` and it is null. What am I missing? I have been staring at this for a bit and can't figure out what is wrong. I even thought it might be the fact that I was using the same name, so create a property called `Text1` which did not work....

Also of note, if I use a regular `TextBox`, then this all works. So, I am fairly certain the problem is with the `EnhancedTextBox` itself

Comment: Did you try `<EnhancedTextBox Text={Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay} />`?

Comment: @gomi42 Updated...sorry I guess I shortened it too much

Comment: @gomi42 I believe `TextBox` defaults to 2way binding anyway

Comment: @geedubb Also, updated...simply a typo in putting it into SO

Comment: @JustinPihony sure - looks OK to me sorry I can't help more

Comment: Is the `TextProperty` actually needed? Can you not just have a regular property that the text box is bound to?

Comment: @Andrew I need it to be a DependencyProperty so that it can be used in XAML

Comment: @JustinPihony Fair enough. I thought I had done something like this before in XAML without it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out after reading [this MSDN about TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Specifically,

> A TemplateBinding is an optimized form of a Binding for template scenarios, analogous to a Binding constructed with **{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}**.

So, I decided to do this explicitly...which would allow me to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` (still  not sure why it doesn't default to `PropertyChanged`)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"....
```

And, now it is working. `TemplateBinding` does not even expose these properties....again, not sure why

Comment: Hey, today I too experienced the same issue and its working now with your solution but if both `TemplateBinding Value` the `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value}` are analogous then why is it accepting! If till now you've figured out and answer it would be kind of you to share here and update your answer. 

Thank You!

Comment: There's no UpdateSourceTrigger on TemplateBinding because TemplateBinding is a one-way binding to the view. The MSDN link you posted states: _A TemplateBinding is always a one-way binding, even if properties involved default to two-way binding._ Not sure why they didn't allow two-way binding though.

Comment: Old, but I struggled with this. Note that you can set the default bindings for your own dependency properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663965/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-custom-dependency-propertys-default-binding-mode-an . In my case I had to use the binding above, with Mode=TwoWay and I'd also set the dependency property default binding to two way. Now binding to a textbox worked without also having to specify there that it had to be two way.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the CallBack when you register the property.

Here's a sample code.

```
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    public void IsSelectedChangedCallback()
    {

        //actions when property changed

    }

    private static void OnSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        userControl.IsSelectedChangedCallback();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedChanged)));
```

Comment: This is not it. The callback would get called, but the bound `MyText` property would still not get updated.