# Is there a way to specify a custom dependency property's default ValidatesOnDataErrors?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

Is there a way to set ValidatesOnDataErrors to True for my custom DependencyProperty, so I do not have to do that every time I bind to it?
Something in the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663965/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-custom-dependency-propertys-default-binding-mode-an).

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string),
            typeof(ErrorTextEdit), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                // Something Here maybe???
            });

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
```

My control could also inherit from TextBox if that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I am afraid not. This is a property of the Binding class rather than of the dependency property. What you could to is to replace the `{Binding}` markup extension in your XAML markup with a custom markup extension that sets the ValidatesOnDataErrors property for you:

[How can i change the default values of the Binding Option in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915679/how-can-i-change-the-default-values-of-the-binding-option-in-wpf)

Or create a custom binding class:

```
public class CustomBinding : Binding
{
    public CustomBinding(string path)
        :base(path)
    {
        this.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:CustomBinding Name}" />
```

Comment: This is one very elegant way of doing it, that I haven't considered.